# Formatting a USB as EXT4 FileSystem format

Tags: cmd.exe, ext4

How do I format an EXT4 Drive on Windows CMD? I'm making a small script for my Java program to run. it involves formatting a drive in ext4.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use WSL2 to access and format a disk as ext4 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/wsl2-mount-disk

But this places a prerequisite on your program to have WSL2 enabled and setup on any system you expect to run on.

As far as I know there are no built-in native ways to do it without installing third party tools such as Paragon ExtFS https://www.paragon-software.com/business/extfs-for-windows/#

Comment: Thank you. I'll try to find alternatives in the future. for now i will use this.

Comment: @RishonJR Most disk partitioning tools also seem to have an option to format as Ext4: https://www.windowscentral.com/how-format-ext4-drive-windows-10 suggests DiskGenius as an option while https://www.diskpart.com/articles/format-ext4-windows-7201.html says that AOMEI Partition Assistant  can do it. Neither seem to say whether it is possible to use a command line to do it though.

Comment: Prerequisite includes Windows 11

Answer (score 1):

There's no native way to do this (format EXT4 from Windows), AFAIK.